# wanting two fingers of the left hand

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning

In Treasure Island there is a description of Black Dog.

> He was a pale, tallowy creature, wanting two fingers of the left hand,
>   and though he wore a cutlass, he did not look much like a fighter.

What does the phrase *wanting two fingers of the left hand* mean?

Why did the Author not use "missing" or "without"?

Comment: Why? It sounds old-fashioned to me, a bit figurative, as though the hand really wanted two more fingers because it was ashamed next to the more filled out right hand. There's the proverb 'for want of a nail...' meaning a nail was lost. It's just how they said missing back then?

Comment: Back then being 1881...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The word **want** is derived from the Old Norse *vanta*, which means "to lack."

The usage in your quote is a bit old yet quite familiar to readers of classic literature.

Should you consult a dictionary, you'll discover that the old meaning is still intact:

**want**

3. to be without or be deficient in:
   to want judgment; to want knowledge.

http://www.dictionary.com/browse/want?s=t